# Why did my computer reboot last night?

Tags: windows-xp, reboot

I left my PC running overnight only to find this morning that that it had rebooted for some reason. Is there some log somewhere that will tell me why my PC shut down?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, simply "run"

```
eventvwr.msc
```

there you find your system logs with informations and errors

Comment: You might also check Windows Update - possibly it did an automatic update that required a reboot.